# Add space after the Exercise environment

Tags: latex

I can't figure out how to add a space (say 3em) after the [Exercise environment](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/)
. I don't want to do it manually for every exercise, but automatically, by using \addtolength
or redefining the environment or something.

For leaving some space in front of it I managed to come up with this:

```
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\vskip 3em\centerline{\textbf{\large\smallpencil
\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle%
\ExerciseHeaderDifficulty\ExerciseHeaderOrigin\medskip}}}
```

I suspect this one must be redefined

```
\def\endExerciseEnv{\termineliste{1}\@EndExeBox}
```

I tried to redefine it but it doesn't work

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With support from #latex @ freenode.net, I found this hack:

```
\makeatletter\def\endExerciseEnv{\termineliste{1}\@EndExeBox\vskip3em}\makeatother
```

If anyone knows a clean way to solve it, feel free to post it.